# Wrong extensionTestsPath on Travis CI only

Tags: visual-studio-code, travis-ci, vscode-extensions

i'm trying to launch tests for my project.

it is is working fine locally when using the launch configuration and also when launching "npm test".

On travis CI, it is failing with (see [here](https://travis-ci.org/jboss-fuse/vscode-atlasmap/builds/477263921#L509))

```
Tests exited with code: 1
The command "npm test --silent" exited with 1.
```

It seems to be due to the fact that extensionTestsPath parameter is wrong, see [here](https://travis-ci.org/jboss-fuse/vscode-atlasmap/builds/477263921#L497):

```
--extensionTestsPath=/home/travis/build/jboss-fuse/vscode-atlasmap/test
```

Although I expect

```
--extensionTestsPath=/home/travis/build/jboss-fuse/vscode-atlasmap/out/test
```

as specified in launch.json [here](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/vscode-atlasmap/pull/12/files#diff-3090e25fed17a6bd57433c6bbadc451aR24):

```
--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceRoot}/out/test
```

How and why the extensionTestsPath used on Travis CI can be different from a local launch? Should I configure something else?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Typescript code wasn't transpiled before.
Shorter fix is to add `npm run compile &&` in the script test value in package.json